# add path to access folders in HTML files

Tags: html

I would like to add some shortcuts in HTML file, the objective is to have a file where I click on links to access to different Windows directory, for example I would like to access to this folder, and I tried to add a link in HTML but it doesn't work  (my folder path is : S:\software\public software\2-RPR\model\list of files

```
<a href="/">S:\software\public software\2-RPR\model>list of files</a>`  in an HTML file ?
```

Comment: After you updated the question, it's not clear what you're asking at this point.  You have a link to `"/"`, which is the root of the web site.  And that link has the *text* of a file system path.  What exactly is the problem?  "How to add in an HTML file" simply involves opening the file in a text editor and typing the code in it, and then saving the file.  What isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

for the record - please state clear questions and do some research before asking.

what you're asking is possible, but why would you? if someone else opens the html from their computer the links won't work any more.

to answer your question - use A tags:
`<a href="/path/to/file/some_file_on_computer.pdf">Link text</a>`

of course it depends on your use case but this is NOT a good idea to do in your case